# Is my use of Fatou's Lemma correct in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I am asked to determine:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}$$

My idea:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}=\limsup_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}$$

and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}=0$

Therefore, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}=0$

Now note that $\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}\geq0,$ for any $x \in ]-\infty,\infty[$

This then implies that: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}d\lambda{x}=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong. The pointwise limit should be
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}}{1+e^{nx}}=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{if $x>0$,}\\
1/2 &\text{if $x=0$,}\\
1 &\text{if $x< 0$.}
\end{cases}$$